# I want scrollviewer fill the grid

Tags: silverlight

```
<navigation:Page 
    d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="1366">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Level3">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ContentPresenter Margin="0 0 4 0" Content="{Binding IconUri}"/>
                <HyperlinkButton x:Name="TemplateLinkButton" Content="{Binding MenuCaption}" NavigateUri="{Binding Uri}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Level2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Level3}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ContentPresenter Margin="0 0 4 0" Content="{Binding IconUri}"/>
                <HyperlinkButton x:Name="TemplateLinkButton" Content="{Binding MenuCaption}"  NavigateUri="{Binding Uri}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Level1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Level2}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ContentPresenter Margin="0 0 4 0" Content="{Binding IconUri}"/>
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=MenuCaption}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"    ShowGridLines="True" Background="Blue">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock  Grid.Row="0"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="Header" Name="textBlockHeader"/>
        <Grid  Grid.Row="1"     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ShowGridLines="True" Background="Pink">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ScrollViewer    Height="Auto" Background="CadetBlue">
                <sdk:TreeView Name="menuTree"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Level1}"     Background="Fuchsia">
            </sdk:TreeView>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <sdk:Frame  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="" Name="contentFrame">
            <sdk:Frame.UriMapper>
                <sdk:UriMapper>
                    <sdk:UriMapping MappedUri="/VIEW/{page}.xaml" Uri="/{page}" />
                </sdk:UriMapper>
            </sdk:Frame.UriMapper>
        </sdk:Frame>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</navigation:Page>
```

This is a default layout header menu and content frame, I want the scrollviewer fill the grid  Grid2's first column. I tried margin `VerticalAlignment` `height= "Auto"`, but it didnt work yet.

Comment: The horizontal and vertical alignment setting to stretch is good, but if your scrollviewer isn't bigger than the grid, the stretch won't make the grid bigger. Some advice when working with grids and filling: Give the background of your grids and children a different color, so you can see what control is stretched and which is not. My guess is that your parent grid isn't stretched at all and the scrollviewer doesn't make your grid stretch.

Comment: I tried set the vertical alignment as stretch but the scollviewer also is not fill the grid.

Comment: could you update the question and post the entire xaml of the page, also mention if the scrollviewer has data when you check it?

Comment: I did as you said ,i found that the LayoutRoot Grid is not fill the browser window ,why?

Comment: Is that page the mainpage, or is it a usercontrol on another page/usercontrol. It's hard to tell if I don't see the bigger picture.

Comment: i updated this post. it is nvigation page ,and the layoutGrid did not fill the browser window, i dont know what's wrong with this code

Comment: I have tried the Xaml and it shows prefectly. Is there anything that is happening in the code that can interfere with the layout? This is a screenshot of how it looks for me: http://i43.photobucket.com/albums/e385/djerry0/snapshot.jpg (I've changed treeview with button, but leaving out that also makes the scrollviewer stretch to the grid's content).

Comment: thank u,I  figure id out what wrong with the code.it's my mistake.

Comment: So it was code-related?
Any way, you should be able to leave out the horizontal/vertical alignments, the children auto behavior will stretch to the content.

Comment: A mainpage SwitchView to the defult page ,but i didnt clear the ColumnDefinitions and RowDefinitions,and all the grid have same background,so it looks like the problem what i said.

Comment: thank u! it's nice way  to set  diffrent background to grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have issues with filling and aligning, a good way to see what container and/or children are causing this is to give everything a different background color. That way, you could see if the grid is stretched, where the child grows to, ...

This question has been resolved already, but I just wanted to share this method, as it has helped you find what was wrong in your case too.

Comment: is it ok now? its  my first time to visiting stackoverflow.com

Comment: It was no problem, I just wondered what the reason was. Btw, Welcome to Stack Overflow.